# How to get the current IPrincipal in custom JsonConverter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net, iprincipal

In my ASP.NET Web API application I'm building a custom `JsonConverter` to convert any `DateTime` string in Json objects to `DateTimeOffset`, using the logged in User's offset.

I have read in [this article](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/246) that the `IPrincipal` is being reset during the serialization process.

A solution was offered in [this article](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2015/02/13/advanced-object-serialization-in-web-api/), which I implemented in my application.

What the author failed to mention is how to actually retrieve the `IPrincipal` inside of the `ReadJson()` method of the JsonConverter.

So I am currently stuck here.

```
internal class CustomDateTimeOffsetConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, 
                                    object value, 
                                    JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is DateTimeOffset)
        {
            var date = (DateTimeOffset)value;
            value = date.LocalDateTime;
        }
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, 
                                    Type objectType, 
                                    object existingValue, 
                                    JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (existingValue is DateTimeOffset)
        {
            // How to get the current logged in IPrincipal?
            // var user =  ...
        }

    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var requestContext = System.Web.DynamicData.DynamicDataRouteHandler.GetRequestContext(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
var user = requestContext.HttpContext.User;
```